# Power BI numeric column miss-reporting as a list in formula

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report where one of the things I need is a percent column. The values come from 2 tables. The devisor column is a whole number but when I add it to the formula, Power BI gives and error saying that the column is a list.

Formula:

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows2", "WeeklyAvg", each  [Sum_Qty]/ItemCountsByWeekCompletedForRedTagRpt_VW[ItemCount])`

Error:
Expression-Error: We cannot apply operator div to types Number and List.
Details:
'Operator=/ Left=48  Right=[List]'

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coworker of mine figured it out. This should be a measure, not a calculated column.

```
WeeklyAvg = DIVIDE(SUM('QA Red Tag NC List'[Sum_Qty]), MAX('ItemCountsByWeekCompletedForRedTagRpt_VW'[ItemCount]))
```